# Node JS + FACEBOOK WEBHOOK

Tags: node.js, facebook, hash

Olá, estou com um problema na confirmação do token SHA1 gerado pelo facebook, acredito que o rawBody esteja errado e não esteja passando o payload como deveria, poderiam dar uma olhada e ver se encontram o problema?

**Middleware para pegar o rawBody sem que vire json:**

```
app.use(
  bodyParser.json({
    verify(req, res, buf) {
      req.rawBody = buf;
    }
  })
);
```

**Código que converte o rawbody com a key "gatepass" diretamente para sha1:**

```
  app.post("/:user/gate", async (req, res, next) => {
    let hmac = crypto.createHmac("sha1", 'gatepass');
    hmac.update(req.rawBody);
    let computedSig = `sha1=${hmac.digest("hex")}`;
    console.log(computedSig);
    console.log(req.headers["x-hub-signature"]);
    //console.log(JSON.stringify(req.body));
    res.send(req.params.user);
  });
```

**Respostas recebidas:**

> sha1=15e1beff7e06e64f49391f88a55a890f42a3951a ► SHA1 GERADO PELO MEU SERVIDOR
>
> sha1=db43b8285f3f4a1295ed1d17c455c8784ccd02e8 ► SHA1 RECEBIDO DO FACEBOOK

*obs.: Já tentei alterar a para o req.body usando toString, usando JSON.stringify, encodeURI e etc... Nenhum deles bate com o resultado.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consegui a resposta, eu precisava transformar o payload em byte e a chave também estava errada, eu estava usando o pagetoken ao invés de usar o app secret...

```
  app.post("/:user/gate", async (req, res, next) => {
    let hmac = crypto.createHmac('sha1', 'APP_SECRET');
    console.log(req.rawBody);
    hmac.update(req.rawBody, 'utf-8');
    let computedSig = `sha1=${hmac.digest("hex")}`;
    console.log(computedSig);
    console.log(req.headers["x-hub-signature"]);
    res.send(req.params.user);
  });
```

O app secret consegue no painel de controle como mostra o print:

> http://prntscr.com/pwexue

Comment: Posta o código para exemplificar melhor

Comment: pronto, deixei também um print de onde conseguir o app_secret